# iOS Push Notification with GCM/Firebase

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been working on an app with push notification, I used Ionic to have Android and iOS. I'm using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). Notifications are already working on Android, but I have some issues with iOS. I set up all the App ID, provisioning profile, certificates, and my device is able to register to GCM. 
But when I try to send a push notification, nothing happens of the push.on('notification') event.

Here is my configuration :

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "xxxxx",
            "alert": "true",
            "badge": "true",
            "sound": "true"
        },
        "ios": {
            "gcmSandbox": "true",
            "senderID": "xxxxx",
            "alert": "true",
            "badge": "true",
            "sound": "true"
        },
        "windows": {}
    });
```

And this is the payload for the notification :

```
{"registration_ids":["n_crmfl5QVo:APA91bEsexRdIgzoFDwN5Y7jX6LCG5r8kbsnPV7cION0MTxFrG4oKc9RvS0hetUtUMqq7GKiskz98DZQ8kooidknK90tx1U64VEWPUS0HcYMJ5IGbeC3Iz1LHtNEtXVF7qk12vkvrJdN"],"notification":{"message":"Test","title":"Message","uid":"58105ee7747f8","quittance":0,"vibrate":1}}
```

Is the payload ok ? Is there an example of a payload for my case (using GCM for iOS)

I don't even receive the notification. I have this message error :

```
{"multicast_id":7395439826576002189,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InternalServerError"}]}
```

On Firebase I created a project, and imported my .p12 certificate, and when creating the app, they gave me a GoogeService-info.plist, is it necessary to make it work ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `priority` as `high` or `content_available` as `true`? Also, please **never** disclose your Sender ID to the public.

Comment: Yes, I tried with both of them.

Comment: I think you need to add it to your Xcode project root. See [steps 4 and 5](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app).

Comment: I tried with this, but still not working. It's weird because I can register my device on GCM, I have the registration Id, but can't send.